# The lifetime of the oobCodes in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a period of life (how long do they expiring) for the `oobCodes` that Firebase sends with actions like password reset or email verify requests? And can it be configured?

Comment: I also want to know this. Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Android SDK you should not have to worry about token expiration. The auth and database SDKs talk to each other and the token is automatically refreshed every hour. This should all be invisible to your application.

Are you having some problem where this is not the case?

I've migrated from the legacy firebase to google-firebase. I've semi-private information the access to which was being controlled using tokens with a large expiry time. This has become impossible with the current limitation.

If we use default Auth providers like (Google, Facebook, Email..), updating "SHA-1 key" in firebase console would enable Automatic token refresh.

But in custom authentication, Firebase SDK need to contact 3rd party server to fetch new token.

Comment: I want to know after what time the token becomes invalid, to know after what time to allow the user to re-request a password recovery again.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Revoke tokens on the backend.
auth.revoke_refresh_tokens(uid)
user = auth.get_user(uid)
# Convert to seconds as the auth_time in the token claims is in seconds.
revocation_second = user.tokens_valid_after_timestamp / 1000
print('Tokens revoked at: {0}'.format(revocation_second))
```

Comment: this is written in python!!